# Uncomment XML File

Tags: xml, bash, sed, adobe

I'm trying to automate how the Adobe CC Cleaner tool creates and then requires the administrator to uncomment specific lines or in our case all lines for each product for a full cleanup as instructed [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/cc-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html#RemoveallorselectedproductsEnterpriseusersonly) for macOS.

I would like to know how to remove/uncomment `<!--` which has leading whitespaces and `-->` on each product/line only without affecting the other lines.

Here an example of the output after generating the cleanup.xml file with the tool on Adobe CC 2020 products:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="eulaAccepted">1</Property>
    </Properties>
    <CreativeCloud>
        <!--<Product productName="AdobeCreativeCloud" version="2.0"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="After Effects" version="17.0.5"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="Camera Raw" version="12.2"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="STI_Color_MotionPicture_HD" version="1.2"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="STI_ColorCommonSet_RGB_HD" version="1.1"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="Bridge" version="10.0.3"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="Illustrator" version="24.0.3"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="CoreSync" version="4.3.34"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="InDesign" version="15.0.2"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="Photoshop" version="21.1.1"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="HD_ASU" version="2.0"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="Lightroom" version="3.2"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="Media Encoder" version="14.0.4"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="CCX Process" version="3.5.1"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="Premiere Pro" version="14.0.4"/>-->
        <!--<Product productName="CC Library" version="3.7.4"/>-->
    </CreativeCloud>
    <AAM></AAM>
    <AdobeIdCredentials></AdobeIdCredentials>
    <CS6></CS6>
    <CS5></CS5>
    <CS4></CS4>
    <CS3></CS3>
</Products>
```

Tried following the instructions provided [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128593/simplest-way-to-comment-uncomment-certain-lines-using-command-line) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/451768/416760) doing the reverse with no luck. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you parsing `xml` with line oriented tool like `sed` and not a syntax aware parser like `xmlstartlet` or `xmllint` or using `xpath`?

Comment: @Inian I thought tools like that couldn't do tasks related to comments such as the OP wants. I guess we'll see if they get an answer using one of those tools.

Answer (score 0):

Try

using `xmlstarlet`

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//comment()'
```

using sed

```
sed '/Product/ s#<!--##g;s#-->##g;'
```

Demo:

```
echo  '<!--<Product productName="AdobeCreativeCloud" version="2.0"/>-->' | sed '/Product/ s#<!--##g;s#-->##g;' 
<Product productName="AdobeCreativeCloud" version="2.0"/>
```

Comment: That's not the way to do it. See Inian's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62255859/uncomment-xml-file#comment110104551_62255859).

Comment: Your `xmlstarlet` command deletes comments - OP say _"uncomment"_

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your real input is as simple and regular as you show in your example then with any sed you can do:

```
$ sed 's/<!--\(.*\)-->/\1/' file
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="eulaAccepted">1</Property>
    </Properties>
    <CreativeCloud>
        <Product productName="AdobeCreativeCloud" version="2.0"/>
        <Product productName="After Effects" version="17.0.5"/>
        <Product productName="Camera Raw" version="12.2"/>
        <Product productName="STI_Color_MotionPicture_HD" version="1.2"/>
        <Product productName="STI_ColorCommonSet_RGB_HD" version="1.1"/>
        <Product productName="Bridge" version="10.0.3"/>
        <Product productName="Illustrator" version="24.0.3"/>
        <Product productName="CoreSync" version="4.3.34"/>
        <Product productName="InDesign" version="15.0.2"/>
        <Product productName="Photoshop" version="21.1.1"/>
        <Product productName="HD_ASU" version="2.0"/>
        <Product productName="Lightroom" version="3.2"/>
        <Product productName="Media Encoder" version="14.0.4"/>
        <Product productName="CCX Process" version="3.5.1"/>
        <Product productName="Premiere Pro" version="14.0.4"/>
        <Product productName="CC Library" version="3.7.4"/>
    </CreativeCloud>
    <AAM></AAM>
    <AdobeIdCredentials></AdobeIdCredentials>
    <CS6></CS6>
    <CS5></CS5>
    <CS4></CS4>
    <CS3></CS3>
</Products>
```

or if you really do need to only apply it to lines that start with spaces then using GNU or OSX/BSD sed for `-E` for EREs:

```
sed -E 's/^([[:space:]]+)<!--(.*)-->/\1\2/' file
```

or with any POSIX sed:

```
sed 's/^\([[:space:]]\{1,\}\)<!--\(.*\)-->/\1\2/' file
```